# c++11 use inner class and/or enum class in base template

Tags: templates, c++11, enums

I have a class that inherits a template.

```
class Foo : public Base<...> {
};
```

Is it possible and how to use an enum class in the base template:

```
class Foo : public Base<EType> {
    enum class EType {
        kI1, kI2, kI3
    };
};
```

Note that I am clear that getting the enum out of the class will allow me to use it in the template.

Comment: `EType` would need to have a known value before the class definition begins.  But it doesn't, so this code is a catch-22.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Exactly what I am asking - having inner class, that I also need to pass to the Base template.

Answer (score 0):

No,  you cannot do this:

```
class Foo : public Base<EType> {
    enum class EType {
        kI1, kI2, kI3
    };
};
```

But you can do this:

```
enum class EType {
    kI1, kI2, kI3
};

class Foo : public Base<EType> {
};
```

You could put them both into a namespace if you want.